# Android GLSL Loop Length

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, glsles

I've been looking into an issue I had with a shader I'm using for an offline process, it's doing a large loop in GLSL using OpenGL ES 2.0, I accidentally deployed and used it on my Samsung Galaxy S6 and noticed something odd, I'm more curious than anything but I managed to boil it down to a very simple shader (note the ACTUAL loop size in each dimension is 42x42 - I just exaggerated in this simple repro).

It's basically an incredibly slow way to create an all white image. Obviously you'd never want to do this, but what happened between devices surprised me (on a Windows PC OGL4.5 it always produces a white image, very slowly of course). If I ran the first implementation (250 in each dimension) I get a blocky and incomplete texture, whereas the second (100 in each dimension) results in a fully white texture like you'd expect.

The blockyness looks like tiles as in TBDR tiles? What I'm wondering is why do some of the tiles fail and produce no output? Shouldn't it just take a really long time as you would expect? Or is there some hidden time out?

Note:

- I only call this once, render to texture and then display the result

// First

```
void main()
{   
    for (float y = 0.0; y <= 250.0; y += 1.0)
    {
        for (float x = 0.0; x <= 250.0; x += 1.0)
        {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0);
        }
    }
}
```

// Second

```
void main()
{   
    for (float y = 0.0; y <= 100.0; y += 1.0)
    {
        for (float x = 0.0; x <= 100.0; x += 1.0)
        {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: White blocky]

[image: White complete]

Comment: I don't know about the specific device, but it's common to have a timeout after which rendering is terminated, to protect the device/computer from getting completely locked up by a broken or malicious app.

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with it: https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/182182-Shader-Program-size-limit